# Can this method be made static?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

Can I make this method static with non problem in an asp.net page (request queuing and thread safety)?

```
public Image MakeImage()
{
    Image objImage = new Bitmap(100, 100);

    Bitmap bitmapimage = new Bitmap(objImage, 100, 100);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmapimage);
    g.DrawImage(new Bitmap(50, 50), new PointF(1, 1));

    return bitmapimage;
}
```

Comment: Sure. If it doesn't need access to any member variables, properties or methods (which it doesn't appear to).

Comment: Did you try? Chances are yes because you are not referencing any page-level variables.

Comment: As a side note, you should dispose `Graphics` (best is to use `using`)

Comment: Yes, but you should wrap the objImage and Graphics objects in a using construct to immediately free the resources no longer needed by them.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, just mark it as such:

```
public static Image MakeImage() {
  ...
```

If it was using some page properties, some instance members, then no, but it's self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes, there's no problem with that. The variables inside the method are all local so there's no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any class member which doesn't use any other instance members on the class it is defined in can be made static.